# Best way to do exact text match in rails/postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a text column in a postgresql table where I need to look for an exact match very often and very quickly. This is a text column in English or Chinese where the length is typically a short sentence or paragraph.

What are my best options? A 'where' query? How would I index the column?

EDIT:
My db migration caused an error:

```
execute "CREATE INDEX idx_src ON translate_logs USING btree (src);"

Caused by:
PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row size 2936 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "idx_src"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

Comment: Are you matching the entire text within the column or a portion of it?

Comment: always only the entire text

Comment: A `WHERE` query with an index should be fast. Here is a dbfiddle with examples on how to create the index and the execution plan showing an index scan: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4e264d078c17d9364a652fe5eac0a59c

Comment: may I ask why BTREE?

Comment: btree is the default anyway I believe. Excluding the `USING` clause you get the same execution plan. Other options just seem more expensive to me. Did you have another index type in mind? You could use `HASH` instead.

Comment: Replicated your example and got an error, i added to my post above

Comment: Hmm, maybe a `GIN` index with to_tsvector is a better option. To be honest, I'd have to research it myself before I could give a strong answer. You'll need some way of shrinking the data to be indexed. Instead of indexing the text itself you could index an MD5 hash, vector, or token representing the text. Your where clause would have to hash the value also.

Comment: Added the MD5 version as one of the answers below, would love to hear and discover more efficient ways

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best answer but answering with what I have so far:

I created a migration with index of an MD5 hash of the value:

```
execute "CREATE INDEX idx_src ON translate_logs ((md5(src)));"
```

This is how I search the column for exact match.

```
TranslateLog.where('md5(src) = md5(?)', text)
```

Would be great to hear of better answers